# How to store multiple variables from a File Input of unknown size in Java?

Tags: java, variables, loops, file-io

I'm a total beginner with my first programming assignment in Java.
For our programming assignment, we will be given a .txt file of students like so:

My problem is: I have a specific class for turning the data from the file into variables to be used for a different class in printing it to the screen. However, I do not know of a good way to get the variables from the input file for the course numbers, since that number is not predetermined. The only way I can think of to iterate over that unknown amount is using a loop, but that would just overwrite my variables every time. Also, the teacher has requested that we not use any JCL classes (I don't really know what this means.)

Sorry if I have done a poor job of explaining this, but I can't think of a better way to conceptualize it. Let me know if I can clarify.

Edit:

```
public static void analyzeData()
{
    Scanner inputStream = null;

    try
    {
        inputStream = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("Programming Assignment 1 Data.txt"));
    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("File Programming Assignment 1 Data.txt could not be found or opened.");
        System.exit(0);        
    }

    int numberOfStudents = inputStream.nextInt();
    int tuitionPerHour = inputStream.nextInt();
    String firstName = inputStream.next();
    String lastname = inputStream.next();
    String isTuitionPaid = inputStream.next();
    int numberOfCourses = inputStream.nextInt();
    String courseName = inputStream.next();
    String courseNumber = inputStream.next();
    int creditHours = inputStream.nextInt();
    String grade = inputStream.next();
```

To show the methods I am using now, I am just using a Scanner to read from the file and for Scanner inputStream, I am using nextInt() or next() to get variables from the file. Obviously this will not work when I do not know exactly how many classes each student will have.

Comment: [Can you provide a sample of code for us to see what you've done?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128572/175248)  There are many ways for us to parse this text file, and we're not sure of how you're approaching it.

Comment: Your professor probably meant JCL - the Java Class Library. It sounds like he's asking you to solve this without leaning on the standard java libraries

Comment: Does that help? Sorry for not including it to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a `Class called Student`
2. Inside the class use `instance variable` like

   String firstName;

   String lastname;

   Boolean isTuitionPaid;   // Boolean cause isPaid will be true or false

   String[] courses;

   int creditHours;

   String grade;
3. Create a constructor of this class which takes the following arguments in its parameter

   Student( String fName,String lName,Boolean istPaid,String[] course,int cHours,String gr)
4. `When you read the data of a student from a file,  store it in the appropriate data type`, as mentioned in the constructor, then create the Object of type Student
5. After creating the `Student object with the data, store it an appropriate Collection`.
   ArrayList, Map, etc

Answer (score 0):

parse the file, create a POJO (lets call it model) and store it in the appropriate collection (possibly an implementation of List would do it). BTW nobody would solve homework, I believe this is a policy here.

Comment: Solve?  No.  Hints?  I don't see a problem with that.

Comment: @bela-vizer to learn more about homework questions see the [homework tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/homework/info). Also [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: That's fine, the programming assignment is more complicated than just this one aspect of it, and I don't really need a solution, because at this point I can't really think of the right way to start doing it. However, I do not know how to create a list and so your answer is a bit confusing to me. I am parsing the file using a Scanner and going word by word with either Scanner inputStream.nextInt() or inputStream.next(), but this will not work when I do not know exactly how many courses each student will have.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this would help:

```
public static void analyzeData()
{
    try
    {
        Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("Programming Assignment 1 Data.txt"));
        String str = inputStream.next();
        String[] s = str.split(" ");
        int numberOfStudents = Integer.parseInt(s[0]);
        int tuitionPerHour = Integer.parseInt(s[1]);
        System.out.println("Number of students: " + numberOfStudents);
        System.out.println("Tuition per hour: " + tuitionPerHour + "\n\n");
        for(int i = 0; i<numberOfStudents; i++)
        {
            String str1 = inputStream.next();
            String[] s1 = str1.split(" ");
            String firstName = s1[0];
            String lastName = s1[1];
            int rollNo = Integer.parseInt(s1[2]);
            String isTuitionPaid = s1[3];
            int numberOfCourses = Integer.parseInt(s1[4]);
            System.out.println("Details of student number " + (i+1));
            System.out.println("Name: " + firstName + " " + lastName);
            System.out.println("Roll No: " + rollNo);
            System.out.println("Is Tuition paid: " + (isTuitionPaid == "Y" ? "Yes" : "No"));
            System.out.println("Number of Courses taken: " + numberOfcourses + "\n");
            for(int j = 0; j<numberOfCourses; j++)
            {
                System.out.println("Details of course no " + (j+1));
                String str2 = inputStream.next();
                String[] s2 = str2.split(" ");
                String courseName = s2[0];
                String courseNumber = s2[1];
                int creditHours = Integer.parseInt(s2[2]);
                String grade = s2[3];
                System.out.println("Course Name: " + courseName);
                System.out.println("Course Number: " + courseNumber);
                System.out.println("Credit Hours: " + creditHours);
                System.out.println("Grade: " + grade + "\n");
            }
        }
    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("File Programming Assignment 1 Data.txt could not be found or opened.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);        
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        System.out.err("IOException has occurred");
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: -1.  See [How to ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10811/175248)